# _.merge/_.assign/_.extend all clones sub-documents in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, merge, mongoose

I have a problem with updating an array of documents in a NodeJS application running MongoDB along with Mongoose.

My problem is when I merge the new document wiht the old one. Both have the variable `content` which holds and array of documents. These documents are all unique, until I merge them, then they becomes clones of the first one. How do I prevent this, I've tried with _.merge, _.extend and _.assign and all three provides the same result.

The old document named `page`:

```
{ _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738c,
  page: 'index',
  __v: 7,
  content:
   [ { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'english',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.uncle</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'deutsch',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.lover</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f } ] }
```

The new document named `req.body`:

```
{ page: 'index',
  __v: 7,
  content:
   [ { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: '56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f' },
     { language: 'english',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.uncle</p>',
       _id: '56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f' },
     { language: 'deutsch',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.lover</p>',
       _id: '56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f' } ] }
```

Result after _.merge:

```
{ _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738c,
  page: 'index',
  __v: 7,
  content:
   [ { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f } ] }
```

Result after _.assign

```
{ _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738c,
  page: 'index',
  __v: 7,
  content:
   [ { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f } ] }
```

Result after _.extend

```
{ _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738c,
  page: 'index',
  __v: 7,
  content:
   [ { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f },
     { language: 'dansk',
       content: '<h1>Lunorth Turneringen</h1><p>Test.bob.hi.cherry..</p>',
       _id: 56806efa7dd9c0c81c39738f } ] }
```